# rscopus scopus_search() only returns first author. Need full author list

Tags: r, scopus

I am performing a bibliometric analysis, and have chosen to use rscopus to automate my document searches. I performed a test search, and it worked; the documents returned by scopus_search() exactly matched a manual check that I performed. Here's my issue: rscopus returned only information on the first author (and their affiliation) of each article, but I need information on all authors/affiliations for each article pulled for my particular research questions. I've scoured the rscopus documentation, as well as Elsevier's Developer notes for API use, but can't figure this out. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

```
query1 <- 'TITLE-ABS-KEY ( ( recreation ) AND ( management ) AND (challenge)'
run1 <- scopus_search(query = query1, api_key = apikey, count = 20,
        view = c('STANDARD', 'COMPLETE'), start = 0, verbose = TRUE,
        max_count = 20000, http = 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus',
        headers = NULL, wait_time = 0)
```

Comment: I believe you need `view = "COMPLETE"` to include all authors in the response.

Comment: @user2554330, I think you are correct. However, I keep getting error 401 when I try this. I suspect my API key doesn't have permission to access complete info for some fields, and rscopus doesn't appear to allow for searches for subsets of fields. Looks like I may be in the market for a different package. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to post an update since I figured out what was going wrong. I was using the university VPN to access the Scopus API, but the IP address associated with that VPN was not within the range of addresses included in my institution's Scopus license. So, I did not have permission to get "COMPLETE" results. I reached out to Elsevier and very quickly got an institution key that I could add to the search. My working search looks as follows...

```
query1 <- 'TITLE-ABS-KEY ( ( recreation ) AND ( management ) AND (challenge)'
run1 <- scopus_search(query = query1, api_key = apikey, count = 20,
        view = c('COMPLETE'), start = 0, verbose = TRUE,
        max_count = 20000, http='https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus',
        headers = inst_token_header(insttoken), wait_time = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to reiterate Brenna's comment - I had the same issue using the VPN  to access the API (which can be resolved by being on campus). Elsevier were very helpful and provided an institutional token very quickly - problem solved.

Otherwise the other workaround I found was to use CrossRef data using `library(rcrossref)`

I used the `doi` column from the `scopusdata` from my original Scopus search:

```
crossrefdata <- scopusdata %>%
  pmap(function(doi){
    cr_works(dois = doi) # returns CrossRef metadata for each doi
  }) %>%
  map(pluck("data")) %>% # cr_works returns a list, select only the 'data'
  bind_rows()
```

You can then manipulate the crossref metadata however you need with full author list.